# How to add a carousel page inside content page?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, carousel

I'm very new for Xamarin Forms. I want to add Carousel page inside the ContentPage.

Is it possible? Because i have Custom navigation bar on ContentPage.

Any one suggest me how to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You can only add a View inside a ContentPage.

Xamarin Forms has it's CarouselView [flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/)

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView) and the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/)

Otherwise a lot of people use this lib

[alexrainman](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView)